# python script error message 'unknown column' - Redhat

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, redhat

My Python script produces `unknown column` error on redhat 8.5 python 3.6.8.
But works without issue on Ubuntu 20.04 with python 3.8.10

Would this be a python or redhat issue? Is it possible to gather more detailed logs?

Link to full script https://github.com/michael-pellegrini/scripts/blob/master/xtime.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess, re, os

def main():
  storage()

def storage():
  output = str.splitlines(os.fsdecode(subprocess.check_output(['lsblk', '-fm', '-o' 'NAME,' 'FSTYPE,' 'FSAVAIL,' 'FSUSE%,' 'MOUNTPOINT,' 'SIZE,' 'OWNER,' 'GROUP,' 'MODE', '-e 7'])))
  print(esc('1;93') + " List of drives, partitions, and details" + esc(0))
  for line in output:
    print(" " + line)
  print('')

def esc(code):
  return f'\033[{code}m'

if __name__=='__main__':
      main()
```

Redhat error message
[image]

Ubuntu output
[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of text. If the image links expire, the question becomes useless to future readers. Just include the text in your question, formatted as a code sample.

Comment: The error comes from `lsblk`; this has nothing to do with Python. Your Red Hat 8.5 system has an older (2.32.1) version of `lsblk`, while Ubuntu 20.04 has `lsblk` version 2.34, which apparently added support for additional fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to clone this repo https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux.git

Then follow this how-to found here.

`https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/next/Documentation/howto-compilation.txt`

```
lsblk --version
lsblk from util-linux 2.38.141-581b1
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is in @larsks comment.
lsblk version 2.32.1 vs 2.34